# pdf corrupted while downloading from URL VB.net/C#

Tags: c#, vb.net, pdf, httpwebrequest, webclient

Problem still there while i tried below three methods.

1. Using Window API "URLDownloadToFile"
2. WebClient Method
   webclient.DownloadFile(url,dest) ''With/Without credientials
3. HTTP WebRequest Method:

public static void Download(String strURLFileandPath, String strFileSaveFileandPath)

```
    {   
        HttpWebRequest wr = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(strURLFileandPath);   
        HttpWebResponse ws = (HttpWebResponse)wr.GetResponse();   
        Stream str = ws.GetResponseStream();   
        byte[] inBuf = new byte[100000];   
        int bytesToRead = (int) inBuf.Length;   
        int bytesRead = 0;   
        while (bytesToRead > 0)    
        {   
            int n = str.Read(inBuf, bytesRead,bytesToRead);   
            if (n==0)   
            break;   
            bytesRead += n;   
            bytesToRead -= n;   
        }   
        FileStream fstr = new FileStream(strFileSaveFileandPath, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write);   
        fstr.Write(inBuf, 0, bytesRead);   
        str.Close();   
        fstr.Close();   
    }
```

Still i m facing the problem, file i am able to download at my local system, but when i open that it show Corrupt pdf.
!!!!I just want to download the pdf from URL and thats my query in VB.net/C# not using response method of ASP.net.
Please help if someone face this real problem.

Thanks in Advance!!!

Comment: Try this :  StreamWriter fstr = new StreamWriter(strFileSaveFileandPath, true, Encoding.UTF8);

Comment: I tried this one also, not helped me,one thing I noticed now that the URL path which i am request to download the PDF is also redirected to other path...means the downloaded file is not PDF at all its html , I can open it by change extension from PDF to html. Hope this make some help to suggest

Comment: Yes you can save with any extension you want.

Answer (score 1):

Your code only writes 100000 bytes of the downloaded PDF and hence every PDF that is bigger than 100000 bytes gets corrupted.

To read more bytes you have to write the contents of every buffer to the FileStream.

The following should do it:

```
HttpWebRequest wr = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(strURLFileandPath);
using (HttpWebResponse ws = (HttpWebResponse)wr.GetResponse())
using (Stream str = ws.GetResponseStream())
using (FileStream fstr = new FileStream(strFileSaveFileandPath, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write))
{
    byte[] inBuf = new byte[100000];
    int bytesRead = 0;
    while ((bytesRead = str.Read(inBuf, 0, inBuf.Length)) > 0)
        fstr.Write(inBuf, 0, bytesRead);
}
```

(It's good coding practice to use a `using` on every `IDisposable` instead of manually closing the streams.)

Comment: I already done that by increasing size but it didn't help me. One more thing ...the file I downloaded have PDF extension but when I change the extension to html than it shows that it is not PDF at all....may be this is due to PDF URL that is redirected to some other path or real PDF path.....which is unable to read by these method can you just tell me how to read that real path of PDF.

Comment: @AKay What is the file size of the corrupted PDF? And what do the contents look like? Is it a readable HTML page? And if it is a public file: Can you post the URL to the PDF you are trying to download?

Comment: Yes it's a readable html ...size is larger than the one I just save with browser Adobe PDF manually...URL is a intranet one will not open outside....URL got .PDF extension at the end if it

Comment: @AKay If you view the HTML in a browser, what essential information does it contain? Does it mention an HTTP status code of 3xx, 4xx or 5xx?

Comment: @AKay You can also compare the HTTP request of your browser with that of your code using [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler). There you can see all HTTP redirects and status codes. What are the differences of the two requests?

Comment: Page contains the html of home page of that URL... don't know how. Just tell me only this ....is it necessary to pass real PDF path to download the PDF

Comment: And how to find that path if one have PDF URL available to download but it is redirecting you..... using any method web client/httprequest/urldownloadtofile/etc